# How to change width of html.DropDownListFor()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have small design question about

```
html.DropDownListFor()
```

How can I change width of `html.DropDownListFor()` ??
For example by css.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you tried `Html.DropDownListFor( new {width:"100"})`

or `Html.DropDownListFor( new {@class:"longDropdownList"})`

**EDIT**

```
<style>
    .MakeWide { width: 200px; }
</style>

<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, new SelectList(new List<string>()), new { @class = "MakeWide" })%>
```

Comment: @Peter M, see my edit.  I have tested this and it works.  If it doesn't work on yours  then we have another type of problem.  Possibly another style is setting the width of all <select input boxes.

Answer (score 12):

`@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Name, new SelectList(new List<string>()), new {style="width:270px;"} );`

Will do the thing. Although better to use css class

Comment: This works for me to adjusting the width. However, how to change the height? I tried to add "width=270px;height=50px" and see no effect on height, why?

Answer (score 2):

In C# you need add @, like this:

```
new { @style = "width: 350px;" }
```

Comment: In C# you only need the @ symbol for reserved words. Style is not a reserved word in C# and therefore doesn't need it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Bootstrap it sets the max width to 280px in site.css.

You probably don't want to change that so to override it for individual controls set:

```
new { style = "max-width:100%;width:350px" }
```