# How to adjust the width of @Html.Dropdownlist for? The data are not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I have used @Html.DropDownLinkFor for selecting the payment options on my system. But what happened is, it doesn't show the default text on the dropdown box. And when you tick an option, it still won't show? How do I make the texts show on the dropdown box or maybe adjust its width?

Here is my codes

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.LevelId, new SelectList(item.GradeLevels, "LevelId", "LevelName", item.LevelId),
"<- Select Level ->",
new { @class = "form-control ddlClass", @id = "LevelId_" + item.TransactionId + "_" + item.StudentId})
</td>
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049498/how-to-change-width-of-html-dropdownlistfor

Comment: How wide is it? And setting the last parameter in the `SelectList` is pointless (you can remove it) but since this appears to be inside a loop then it will never bind to your model anyway since your creating multiple `<select>` elements with the same `name` attribute (you need a `for` loop and use indexers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of the DropDownList helper must be an IEnumerable.

Please Try Step By Step By.

Step-1)

```
@Html.DropDownList(
"ListId", 
Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(),"<- Select Level ->", 
new { style = "width: 360px;" }
```

)

Step-2)
that you want to use to bind to:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
"ListId", 
Model.PaymentMethodList,"<- Select Level ->", 
new { style = "width: 360px;" }
```

)

Step-3)

avoid cluttering your HTML with styles you should use an external CSS:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ListId, 
    Model.PaymentMethodList,"<- Select Level ->", 
    new { @class = "mydropdown" }
)
```

Your External Css Code

```
.mydropdown{
width: 360px;
```

}

if you are still the problems please check your css and script or share much more your code.

Comment: The 2nd argument must be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` which is exactly what OP's code (`new SelectList(item.GradeLevels, "LevelId", "LevelName", item.LevelId)`) is.

Comment: Hi I tried this, along with the correction and no success. Only thing different is that the list is inside a span with the bootstrap class: col-lg-push-4. Any thoughts?